# How to search for a string in linux

Tags: linux, awk, sed, grep

How to extract only /app/xxxx field in the below lines and add df -P -T command to the extracted strings and save the output in the below format

```
edlp_nps_app:x:23449:5000:EDLP_NPS_APP (HP):/app/edlp_nps_app:/bin/bash
genxp_app:x:23414:15887:GENXP_APP (HP):/app/genxp_app:/bin/bash
icegnapp:x:21697:15954:ICEGNAPP (HP):/app/icegnapp:/bin/bash
icegnftp:x:21554:15416:ICEGNFTP 
(HP):/app/icegnftp:/usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server

df -P -T /app/XXXXX
df -P -T /app/edlp_nps_app
O/P:
Filesystem                 Type 1024-blocks     Used Available Capacity 
Mounted on
/dev/mapper/rootvg-rootvol ext4   144365708 27057836 110769428      20% /
```

Output i require is FS, type, Mounted on, appname

/dev/mapper/rootvg-rootvol    ext4     /         /app/edlp_nps_app

I tried it awk command but it didnt work

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk` test if 6th field starts with `/app`, if true print 6th field

```
awk -F':' '$6~/^\/app/{print "df -P -T "$6}' infile | bash
```

To save in file

```
awk -F':' '$6~/^\/app/{print "df -P -T "$6}' infile | bash > outfile
```

To avoid printing of header multiple times you may pipe another `awk` like below

```
awk -F':' '$6~/^\/app/{print "df -P -T "$6}' infile | bash | awk 'FNR==1{print;next}/Filesystem/{next}1' >outfile
```

Test Results :

input :

```
$ cat file
edlp_nps_app:x:23449:5000:EDLP_NPS_APP (HP):/app/edlp_nps_app:/bin/bash
genxp_app:x:23414:15887:GENXP_APP (HP):/app/genxp_app:/bin/bash
icegnapp:x:21697:15954:ICEGNAPP (HP):/app/icegnapp:/bin/bash
icegnftp:x:21554:15416:ICEGNFTP 
(HP):/app/icegnftp:/usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server
```

Output:

```
$ awk -F: '$6~/^\/app/{print "df -P -T "$6}' file 
df -P -T /app/edlp_nps_app
df -P -T /app/genxp_app
df -P -T /app/icegnapp
```

Comment: i have used the following command: grep -Eo '^[^  :]+'  to identify first field and the  used sed "s%^%echo df -P -T /app/%"  but in output along with FS,   Mounted on, Type i also need the app name

Comment: If use this echo     'df -P -T /app/b9jx_appid'    /app/b9jx_appid  i get the output as i desired , but how do do that for a file with 200 records.  output of the cmd:                                                                                                                                                                                           
 Filesystem Type 1024-blocks Used Available Capacity Mounted on /dev/mapper/rootvg-rootvol ext4 144365708 27058072 110769192 20% / /app/b9jx_appid

Answer (score 0):

> extract /app/xxx

first we drop the lines that do not contain /app

```
sed '/\/app/!d'
```

then we extract the /app/...

```
's|.*\(/app/[^:]*\).*|\1|'
```

combined:

```
sed '/\/app/!d;s|.*\(/app/[^:]*\).*|\1|'
```

> Output i require is FS, type, Mounted on, appname
>
> /dev/mapper/rootvg-rootvol ext4 / /app/edlp_nps_app

Let's tweak the df's output a little bit by having it supply only the relevant fields

```
df /app/foo --output=source,fstype,target
```

I do not believe we can get df to drop the header, so we strip it

```
df /app/foo --output=source,fstype,target | sed '1d'
```

I will append the app name manually and put it all together in a script named "magic.sh":

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ ! -f "$1" ]
then
    echo "Input file does not exist!"
    exit 1
fi

if [ -f "$2" ]
then
    echo "Output file already exists!"
    exit 2
fi

sed '/\/app/!d;s|.*\(/app/[^:]*\).*|\1|' $1 | while read -r app
do 
    echo "$(df $app --output=source,fstype,target | sed '1d') $app" >> $2
done
```

Assuming the specified input is in a file named "input" and you want the result in a file named "output", this is how to call it:

```
sh magic.sh input output
```